# How to go about deep mock or stub with Spock?

Tags: mockito, spock

How to do the equivalent of Mockito's deep mock / stub (RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS ) in Spock? Something like:

```groovy
Changes changes = Mock()
changes.id(_).current() >> aChangeApi
```

While in Mockito it'd be:

```java
Changes changes = mock(Changes.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
when(changes.id(any()).current()).thenReturn(aChangeApi);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can do something like:

```
Changes changes = Stub()
changes.id(_) >> Stub(<ReturnedClass>) {
    current() >> aChangeApi
}
```

This just returns a stub which can then be further mocked.
I'm not that familiar with Mockito but from a bit of google searching this seems to be the way that should get a similar result.

Comment: I think you need to change `changes() >> aChangeApi` to `current() >> aChangeApi`, to properly match the example provided in the question.